# React Native, Ternary change style and button's name at each click

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

This React Native code works fine with changing the button's style on click. I want it to be able to change the button's name too to numbers from the defined list KEYNOS (instead showing the A, B, C...etc I want it to replace it with 1, 2, 3...etc). to make new List for numbers and use map to loop through it.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

const KEYWORDS = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"];
const KEYNOS = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"];
export default class App extends Component {
state = {
    keywordsList: [],
    keynosList: [],
};

toggleKeyword = (keyword) => {
    const { keywordsList } = this.state;
    let list = keywordsList;
    let index = -1;
    if ((index = keywordsList.indexOf(keyword)) != -1) {
        list.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
        list.push(keyword);
    }
    this.setState({ keywordsList: list });
};
toggleKeyno = (keyno) => {
    const { keynosList } = this.state;
    let list = keynosList;
    let index = -1;
    if ((index = keynosList.indexOf(keyno)) != -1) {
        list.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
        list.push(keyno);
    }
    this.setState({ keynosList: list });
}
render() {
    const { keywordsList } = this.state;
    const { container, selectedKeywordStyle, buttonStyle, textStyle } = styles;
    return (
        <View style={container}>
            {KEYNOS, KEYWORDS.map((item) => (
                <TouchableOpacity
                    style={keywordsList.find((element) => element == item) ? selectedKeywordStyle : buttonStyle}
                    onPress={() => this.toggleKeyword(item)}
                >
                    <Text style={textStyle}>{item}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            ))}
        </View>
    );
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-around",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    paddingTop: 50,
},
textStyle: {
    fontSize: 16,
    padding: 8,
    textAlign: "center",
},
buttonStyle: {
    width: "30%",
    backgroundColor: "gray",
    borderRadius: 15,
    margin: 5,
},
selectedKeywordStyle: {
    width: "30%",
    backgroundColor: "blue",
    borderRadius: 15,
    margin: 5,
},
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the same condition you already have but pass 2nd argument as well for `map` to attach the index so you can correlate the KEYWORDS with KEYNOS

```
{
  KEYWORDS.map((item, index) => (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={
        keywordsList.find((element) => element == item)
          ? selectedKeywordStyle
          : buttonStyle
      }
      onPress={() => this.toggleKeyword(item)}
    >
      <Text style={textStyle}>
        {keywordsList.find((element) => element == item)
          ? KEYNOS[index]
          : item}
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  ))
}
```

---

You can also reduce the time complexity by minimizing the iterations

```
{
  KEYWORDS.map((item, index) => {
    let style, text;

    if (keywordsList.find((element) => element === item)) {
      style = selectedKeywordStyle;
      text = KEYNOS[index];
    } else {
      style = buttonStyle;
      text = item;
    }

    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        key={index} // make sure you assign a unique key for each item
        style={style}
        onPress={() => this.toggleKeyword(item)}
      >
        <Text style={textStyle}>{text}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  })
}
```